# retrieve user->ID from wordpress to aanother php site

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a PHP application `custom_appli` in `/var/www/httpdocs`.
Wordpress is installed on the same server in `/var/www/httpdocs/new_cms/wordpress`.

I need to retrieve `user->ID` using `SESSION` of `custom_appli`.

I have tried to insert :

```
    require( './new_cms/wp-snapshots/wp-blog-header.php' );
    global $user;
    $user = wp_get_current_user();
    echo "ID :".$user->ID;
```

writing `wp-load` instead of `wp-blog-header` doesn't change anything no matter whether I use `include` or `require_once`.

Could you please give me a link or advice on how to obtain user from `SESSION`?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Formatting, grammar, readability improvements.

Comment: @jan : Thanks for these improvements... my written english is poor...I just notice a bit confusing  : " need to retrieve user->ID using SESSION of custom_appli." I confirm i want to retrieve user->id in custom_appli FROM wordpress. The first login-in is in wordpress and i want to avoide a second identification.

Answer (score 0):

Details and info are sparse, but here's how I would do it (I know about 5 methods, these are the least painful):

As mentioned, `wp_get_current_user()` gets you close, but that is generally only usable on the page for the user as in  "on load" only.  So from the WP served page you can get user ID (and all other info) and the session and have something that is usable. There are many ways to use that data to solve your problem, not really smooth all the time. Session data is etherial, beware.

Another way to go about it is to use `wp-load.php` and wrap it in middleware. this script bootstraps WP and allows queries and similar in the "bootstrapped" wordpress environment providing the applications internal API. I would consider adding wp-load to custom_appli "in the right way" and use that as middleware between the 2 applications.  You will still need to identify the user as in many cases.

Without more information it is hard to guide you, but I can tell by your needs and the code already in the post that you are setting up for possible problems with dependencies, possible name-spacing collisions(`$user` is something that could bite you as a global), and a myriad of other ways to loose time. If custom_appli needs a user ID, send it the user from WP on page load or similar.

When/why do you need that info? What is the flow?

You can also traverse a lot via session ID info too (depending on configuration).

FWIW I have passed user information successfully from 2 freestanding applications on different servers, it was very hard to do correctly, but it is possible.

### Update after clarification

As mentioned "wordpress-user and cusstom-appli have same users" is possibly a replication of functionality, specifically running 2 tables(?) or logic. Just some feedback.

Basically you are wanting to hook the "logged in" status of a WP user.  I see no mention of:

- FK/relationships built on user (easy but a little more work)
- ACL/permission based access on custom appl
- No serializing of data or similar to the WP user (user in general)

Any of the above might have me change the solution. Here is a pretty clean prototype I wrote for you [that is about 15 lines of code](https://gist.github.com/datamafia/94876620ee170820cf296ca15d899257).

It follows some code from wp and essentially:

- Makes sure PHP session is initialized via the theme functions.php
- Uses the WP login (authentication) success to add a var to the session
- On logout unsets the var (!IMPORTANT!)
- Also makes sure the session is set when not logged in or the key is not present
- Is easy to pick up outside of WP via session (custom_appl.php)

I tested this and it worked fine locally on one of my installs, I don't see any reason why it would give you problems.  I would harden this a little more, but this is only a prototype showing how to use the key tools in PHP and WP.

Comment: Thanks a lot for these first approaches. The "workflow" is : 1/The user logs in on wordpress. 2/if he is a registired user, he can acces to the features of custom-appli, who needs only the user-id. wordpress-user and cusstom-appli have same users, with same id's.3/ custom-appli get the user_id and after..no more problem it works ... I wonder if i would have to put the file custom-appli_identification.php inside wordpress directory and then redirect to stuff of custom_appli ?

Comment: I wrote and tested a prototype for you, added to the edited message.

Comment: It woks like a charm ! you save me a lot of hours of work. And your comments are very usefull. why you don't put this comment in a answer, so that i can upvote you and other can benefit of this code ?

Comment: Accept the answer, its the best way to go @Gerard13007 and that will benefit everyone. Thx and glad it worked.

Answer (score -1):

[wp_get_current_user()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_current_user/) is a function in wp-includes/pluggable.php, which is loaded by wp-settings.php. I'm not sure how exactly WordPress bootstraps itself but I'd try to include **wp-settings.php** if anything.

Comment: Thanks a lot for these first approaches. The "workflow" is :

Comment: Thanks a lot for these first approaches. The "workflow" is : 1/The user logs in on wordpress. 2/if he is a registired user, he can acces to the features of custom-appli, who needs only the user-id. wordpress-user and cusstom-appli have same users, with same id's.3/ custom-appli get the user_id and after..no more problem it works ... I wonder if i would have to put the file custom-appli_identification.php inside wordpress directory and then redirect to stuff of custom_appli ?